# Dynamic Nivo Slider with Google Drive

Tags: jquery, html, slider, blogs, nivo-slider

Having successfully used Nivo Slider before (albeit in a PHP environment -- OSCommerce), and also very much liking Google Drive, I wonder whether it's possible to set up Nivo Slider jQuery in a way that will allow it to query either a Google Spreadsheet for picture links or directly access a specified folder inside Google Drive.

Is there any easy way to achieve this or would I be better of relying on the combination of Nivo Slider and Flickr?

My goal is to have an easy, amateur friendly setup for a Google Blogger blog.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a Google Spreadsheet, or could it be a simple txt file? From that you could parse the text file for links in PHP, and supply them to the Nivo Slider script. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this won't be of much help, as I'm looking for a solution that works with Google Blogger. So there's no PHP available.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that. Would using jQuery to load and parse the text file be a viable solution?